# pip install MySQL-python

Tags: python, macos, mysql-python

I'm trying to install MySQLdb for Python on Mac OS.
When I digit `pip install MySQL-python` shell returns to this:

```
 Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "/private/var/folders/9h/2lp9kx993ygbrfk1lxr0sz500000gq/T/pip-install-7xyyBe/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 17, in 
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 53, in get_config
        libraries = [ dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith(compiler_flag("l")) ]
      File "setup_posix.py", line 8, in dequote
        if s[0] in "\"'" and s[0] == s[-1]:
    IndexError: string index out of range

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/9h/2lp9kx993ygbrfk1lxr0sz500000gq/T/pip-install-7xyyBe/MySQL-python/
```

What can I do? I searched everywhere but I couldn't find an answer.
(I had installed Python 2.7)

Comment: Perhaps try installing via `pip install mysqlclient` if you need legacy python compatibility maybe try downloading `brew` and running `brew install mysql-connector-c` or `brew install mysql`. Let me know if any of that helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed the error. If anyone have this error just follow these steps:

1. First of all install mysql connector

   > brew install mysql-connector-c

   2. You have to modify lines in mysql_config (this is an alias)

   > vim /usr/local/bin/mysql_config

   (I sincerely consider to open mysql_config with a file editor, you can find the 
    exact folder here)

   > /usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/bin/

   3. Replace these lines.

   ```
     # Create options 
     libs="-L$pkglibdir"
     libs="$libs -l "
   ```

   should be:

   ```
     
     # Create options 
     libs="-L$pkglibdir"
     libs="$libs -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"
   ```

   4. Set environment variable

   > brew info openssl

   it would tell what’s needed

   ```
    For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
         LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
         CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
     For pkg-config to find this software you may need to set:
         PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig
   ```

   5. Then you can install MySQL

   > pip install MySQL-python

   6. You can test if MySQL is installed with this:

   > python -c "import MySQLdb"

   Hope this works also for you!