# MacOS: "pip install MySQL-python" returning an error: "_mysql.c:44:10: fatal error: 'my_config.h' file not found"

Tags: python, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I have looked all over the internet including here. I have tried all the suggested solutions, but none of them worked.
Here is the error message I get `_mysql.c:44:10: fatal error: 'my_config.h' file not found`

Could the problem come from the fact that my MySQL and Python versions are not compatible?
MySql version:Ver 8.0.21 for osx10.15 on x86_64 (Homebrew)
Python version:Python 2.7.16

Could that simply be it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This solution is for macOS users**

After struggling a while on this issue I finally solved it, and it was pretty simple in the end.
Maybe this will help others too, because I have seen this issue around a lot during my research. There are plenty of solutions out there, that worked for some and not for others. None of them worked for me.

Before you go into a copy/paste of commands rampage in your terminal, you might want to check your **MySQL version**. Because apparently MySQL only supports the `MySQL-python` dependency until **version 5.7**. So I just had to **downgrade my MySQL 8 to 5.7**, and then I could finally run the pip install MySQL-python command, and it worked!

So if you have a MySQL version higher than 5.7, you might want to downgrade.
To that, type in these commands in your terminal:

`brew unlink mysql`

`brew install mysql@5.7`

Then, try `mysql --version` If `mysql` is still red, run this command:

`export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin`

And you should finally be able to run:

`pip install MySQL-python`

This worked for me, hope it will for you!

Answer (score 1):

Download whl file from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python). according to your pc architecture.(win32 or amd64) These are prebuilt binaries.

open cmd to the location of the file.
`pip install file_name`

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it says ```a Python 3 compatible fork of MySQL-python``` 
I have python 2.7, will it still work?

Comment: Dont download mysqlclient. That is ```a Python 3 compatible fork of MySQL-python```. ```cp27``` in the name means it is compatible with python 2.7

Comment: Thanks again for your help. But is I am wondering if these files are just for windows?
I am working on a mac, and with both files I get this message: ```ERROR: MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform```

Comment: @OlivierGirardot, yes.they are only for windows. win32 in text will help you identify that.For mac you might have to refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123044/pip-install-mysql-python)

Comment: Yes of course, but I tried it anyway, I am that desperate lol
I also followed the instructions from the link you posted, no luck either.
Then I stumbled across another reply, saying that the issue could very well be coming from the MySQL version that no longer supports MySQL-Python

Comment: OK, problem finally solved! It was that MySQL only supports the ```MySQL-python``` dependency until version 5.7. So I just had to downgrade my MySQL 8 to 5.7, and then I could finally run the ```pip install MySQL-python``` command, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

try installing,

```
pip install pmysql
pip install mysql-connector
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

all are the same

Comment: Thank you Ahmad, but I had already tried that. In the meantime I found the solution which was to downgrade my MySql version (see accepted solution). But thanks a lot anyway!